# Old Russian or Soviet-era cartoon movie about a servant, a prince and a princess

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I’d appreciate any help remembering the title of an old Russian or Soviet-era cartoon movie.

The story is about a prince and his servant, who go on an adventure to rescue a princess from a dragon. The princess's name is Vasilisa the beautiful. During the adventure, it is the prince's servant who takes all the risks and completes all the missions. I remember that during one of the missions the servant was transformed into a dog, and in another he went inside the house of an old witch. Finally, he manages to defeat the dragon by cutting the dragon's heads with something like a magical water stream given to him during the adventure, and rescues the princess. As a reward, the princess marries him instead of the prince.

Comment: This sounds interesting and a bit familiar to me. Was this a stop-motion animated film or a traditional type of cartoon? I assume you believe this is 1960s to 1980s and such by the way you mention “Soviet-era” correct?

Comment: Was there moose and squirrel?

Comment: Does it seem related to this 2006 Russian animated movie? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobrynya_Nikitich_and_Zmey_Gorynych

Comment: yes  JakeGould I believe it was between 60s and 80s, it was a traditional cartoon, there was no moose nor squirrel, and it's not related to the mentioned 2006 movie.

Comment: I remember more details now, the princess was called vasilisa the beautiful (I found stories with the same name but it was different from what I'm asking about), she was kidnapped by an old wizard who transforms to a dragon with many heads at the final battle and the servant was able to cut his heads by some thing like a magical water stream given to him during the adventure. thanks for your help guys

Comment: What's the cryllic spelling of vasilisa?

Comment: I have no idea, I tried to search with English pronunciation but I didn't get the answer I'm looking for

Comment: I fffffound it, it's called Сказка сказывается, cde you inspired me, I searched google images for the Russian translation of Vasilisa the beautiful and I found a screenshot of the movie. thanks a lot for all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Cyrillic [***Сказка Сказывается***](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F) literally translated as **"The Fairy Tale"**, alternatively titled **"Another's Tale to Tell"** or **"Tale to be Told"** is a 1970 cartoon short by written by Boris Larin directed by Ivan Aksenchuk.

It is based on the archetypical Slavic fairy tales of the Heroic [Ivan Tsarevich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Tsarevich) or [Ivan the Fool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_the_Fool), The Maiden [Vasilisa the Beautiful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasilisa_the_Beautiful) or [Vasilisa the Wise/Frog Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frog_Princess) (not related to the germanic fairy tale of Frog Prince/Princess and the Frog), and the [Villainous Immortal Koschei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koschei).

[Koschei the Deathless] [Russian Literal: Bag of Bones] kidnapped Vasilisa the Beautiful, locking her away and torturing her so people will try to rescue her. There is a Prince who comes to save her but won't life a finger to do it. His faithful servant Ivan does it instead, dealing with a cannibalistic witch, a riddle loving living waterfall, and finally Koshcei turned into a 3 headed dragon.

As mentioned, the servant does all the work, does get turned into a (very lion-y) dog, ***goes to retrieve a knife from the house of the famous old witch of fairy tale lore, Baba-Yaga***, and in the end wins Vasilisa's hand in marriage.

English and Spanish subtitles available by Chapaev & Eus and Don Medina respectfully (Use the youtube setting/gear button to change):